# list is not expanding / collapsing for second time

Tags: android

Problem: When I click on Custom/Random nothing is happening.
 (please see screenshot below).

I implemented ExpandListView successfull using  [this](https://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html) example, but in my case data is coming from database, that is only difference. I debug my code, it is going inside `expandAll()` and when I run application, it is bydefault came with expanded list.

***Screenshot of my current code, actually, I impl expandeListview in dialog box and inflate row using expandlistadapter***

[image]

**My code:**
**ExpandableCategoryAdapter:**

```
public class ExpandableCategoryAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = ExpandableCategoryAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    private Context context;
    private List<CategoryHeader> originalList;
    private List<CategoryHeader> headerList;
    private HamburgerMenuListener menuInterface;

    public ExpandableCategoryAdapter(Context context, List<CategoryHeader> generalList, HamburgerMenuListener menuInterface) {
        this.context = context;
        this.headerList = generalList;
        this.originalList = generalList;
        this.menuInterface = menuInterface;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0 || position == 6;
    }


    private CategoryHeader getItem(int position) {
        return originalList.get(position);
    }

    private void showLog(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return headerList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        List<CustomCategory> countryList = headerList.get(groupPosition).getCategoryList();
        return countryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return headerList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        List<CustomCategory> countryList = headerList.get(groupPosition).getCategoryList();
        return countryList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        CategoryHeader categoryHeader = (CategoryHeader) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_custom_category_list, null);
        }

        TextView heading = view.findViewById(R.id.header_view);
        heading.setText(categoryHeader.getHeaderName().trim());

        return view;
    }

    public void filterData(String query) {

        query = query.toLowerCase();
        headerList.clear();

        if (query.isEmpty()) {
            headerList.addAll(originalList);
        } else {

            for (CategoryHeader categoryHeader : originalList) {

                List<CustomCategory> countryList = categoryHeader.getCategoryList();
                List<CustomCategory> newList = new ArrayList<CustomCategory>();
                for (CustomCategory customCategory : countryList) {
                    if (customCategory.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                        newList.add(customCategory);
                    }
                }
                if (newList.size() > 0) {
                    CategoryHeader nContinent = new CategoryHeader(categoryHeader.getHeaderName(), newList);
                    headerList.add(nContinent);
                }
            }
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        CustomCategory customCategory = (CustomCategory) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_general_list, null);
        }

        TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_category_item);


        if (customCategory != null && customCategory.getName() != null) {
            name.setText(customCategory.getName().trim());
        }


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public class MyViewHolderItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textViewItem;
        private ImageView imageViewIcon;
        private ImageView hamburgerMenu;
        private Button customImageViewIcon;

        public MyViewHolderItem(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_category_item);
            imageViewIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_category_icon);
            customImageViewIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_custom_category_icon);
            hamburgerMenu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hamburger_menu);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //          menuInterface.onClickListItem(originalList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getCustCategoryId());
                }
            });

            hamburgerMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (menuInterface != null) {
                        //          menuInterface.onClickHamburger(originalList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getCustCategoryId());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class MyViewHolderHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView headerView;

        public MyViewHolderHeader(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            headerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.header_view);
        }
    }
}
```

**CategoryDialog:**

```
public class CategoryDialog extends BaseClass implements View.OnClickListener, Callback<String>, HamburgerMenuListener, ResultListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {
    private static final String TAG = CategoryDialog.class.getSimpleName();
    int i = 0;
    private String landlineName, getProviderName, defaultName = "", phoneNum, customCategoryName, selected = "", getConsumerNum, getAccountNum, getOwnerName;
    private long tempId = 0, categoryId, getCustomCategoryId, providerId, customCategoryId = 0, subProviderId;
    private boolean stop = true, insurance, isEditPayment = false, isDeletedSQLite = false, isDeletedServer = false, isClicked = false;
    private ExpandableCategoryAdapter expandableCategoryAdapter;
    private List<CustomCategory> categories, customCategories;
    private RecyclerView dialogRecyclerView;
    private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    private DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter;
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences profilePreference;
    private View promptsView;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private CustomCategory customCategory;
    private List<Reminder> dialogListItems;
    private ImageView info;
    private DialogListAdapter dialogListAdapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private ProviderDialog providerDialog;
    private TextView inputInsuranceProvider, textViewError, inputBillProvider, errorView, information, subProviderError, providerError, customProviderError, consumerError, ownerError;
    private EditText userInput, inputConsumerNumber, name, inputAccountNumber, inputCustomProvider;
    private ProvidersInfo providersInfo;
    private AlertDialog informationDialog, mDialog;
    private CategoryListener categoryListener;
    private General provider, subProvider;
    private RelativeLayout relativeProvider, subProviderLayout, accountLayout, customLayout;
    private LinearLayout spinnerLayout;
    private List<General> mainInsuranceList = new ArrayList<>();
    private CustomSpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter;
    private CustomSpinnerClass spinInsuranceList;
    private ArrayList<CategoryHeader> headerArrayList = new ArrayList<CategoryHeader>();
    private CategoryHeader categoryHeader;

    public CategoryDialog(Context context, Activity activity) {
        super(context, activity);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
    }

    private void init() {
        categories = new ArrayList<>();
        customCategories = new ArrayList<>();
        dbAdapter = RemindMe.getInstance().adapter;
        dialogListItems = new ArrayList<>();
        profilePreference = context.getSharedPreferences(PROFILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
        providerDialog = new ProviderDialog(context);
        providerDialog.setResultListener(this);
        getDataFromSharedPref();
    }

    private void loadSomeData() {
        categoryHeader = new CategoryHeader("Custom", customCategories);
        headerArrayList.add(categoryHeader);

        categoryHeader = new CategoryHeader("Random", categories);
        headerArrayList.add(categoryHeader);

        categoryHeader = new CategoryHeader("General", categories);
        headerArrayList.add(categoryHeader);
    }

    public void setCategoryListener(CategoryListener listener) {
        this.categoryListener = listener;
    }

    private void setClickListener() {
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void showCategoryDialog() {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_category_dialog_layout, null);
        init();
        findViewById();
        setClickListener();
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        recyclerView();
        mDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);

        mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.colorWhite);
        mDialog.show();
    }

    private void findViewById() {
        expandableListView = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
        fab = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    }

    private void recyclerView() {
        addToCategories();
        loadSomeData();
        showLog("headerArrayList: " + headerArrayList.size());
        //expandableCategoryAdapter = new ExpandableCategoryAdapter(context, categories, this);
        expandableCategoryAdapter = new ExpandableCategoryAdapter(context, headerArrayList, this);
        //       expandableListView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       /* final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        expandableListView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        expandableListView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());*/
        try {
            expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableCategoryAdapter);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        showLog("1");
        expandAll();
      listener();
    //      expandableCategoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //     expandableCategoryAdapter.refresh(headerArrayList);
}

private void listener() {
    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            for (int i = 0; i < headerArrayList.size(); i++) {
                if (i != groupPosition) {
                    expandableListView.expandGroup(i);
                }

            }
        }
    });
}private void expandAll() {
        showLog("2");
        int count = expandableCategoryAdapter.getGroupCount();
        showLog("3 :"+ count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            showLog("4");
            expandableListView.expandGroup(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: for ( int i = 0; i < groupList.getCount(); i++ ) {
    groupList.expandGroup(i);
 }

Comment: @AjayPandya, but I printed log  in followed example also, in that also expandAll method called once. In example case, it is written inside onCreate and in my code, it is written inside init method, when showDialog is called.

Comment: @AjayPandya where I have to implement this for loop?

Comment: inside expandAll()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195973/discussion-between-piyush-and-arpi-singh).

Comment: @AjayPandya Thanks, it's solved. Please see updated question.

Comment: @ArpiSingh if it resolved than it's nice if you post question with proper data than may your problem get solved quick as you not paste xml file

Comment: @AjayPandya umm..you're right ajay, but I thought there is some prob with Adapter, I didn't think abt xml. BTW thanks again and can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886991/data-comes-from-getchid-but-not-store-into-getchildview

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Class******Adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
private Context context;
private List<ModelClassObj> ModelClassObjs;

public ExpandableVocherDetailsAdapter(Context context,List<ModelClassObj> 
ModelClassObjs)
{
this.context = context;
this.ModelClassObjs = ModelClassObjs;
}

public void refresh(List<ModelClassObj> ModelClassObjs)
{
    this.ModelClassObjs   = ModelClassObjs;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    if(ModelClassObjs!=null && ModelClassObjs.size()>0)
        return ModelClassObjs.size();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    ModelClassObj  obj  = ModelClassObjs.get(i);

    EditText tvCreatedBy,tvCreatedOn,tvDescription,tvVoucherNumber,tvcancelReason,tvcancelBy,tvCancelApproveBy,tvCancelApproveOn,tvdocph,tvdocemail;
    LinearLayout tvCancelReasonHed,lldocph_email,llcancel_appro;

    view  =  LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.exp_vocher_child,null);

    tvCreatedBy     = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCreatedBy);

    tvCreatedBy.setText(obj.getCreatedBy());

    return view;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    final ModelClassObj  obj  = ModelClassObjs.get(i);

    TextView tvDoctorName,tvvpAmnt,tv_vp_payment,tv_vp_ReceipientType;
    ImageView ivIndicator;
    LinearLayout llParent;

    view = 
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.exp_vocher_parent_cell,null);

    tvDoctorName             = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDoctorName);


    tvDoctorName.setText(obj.getDoctorName());

    if(b==true)
        ivIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
    else
        ivIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);

    return view;
}
}
```

Activity Class

```
expandableLisView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new 
ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            for (int i = 0; i < voucherDetailsObjs.size(); i++) {
                if (i != groupPosition) {
                    exlvVocherDetail.collapseGroup(i);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if this adapter class is useful click on accept answer

Comment: Hello Sandeep, really thanks for reply, please stick with me to solve this issue. I can see that you added refresh method. In that which list should I pass? Group or child?

Comment: in xml file in replace  RecycleView with ExpandableListView

Comment: I did everything, I changed already and there is no compile time error.

Comment: and from where I should call refresh method?

Comment: what is voucherDetailsObjs and exlvVocherDetail group and child?

Comment: voucherDetailsObjs is main ArrayList<> passing to the adapter    
exlvVocherDetail is the Object in the above ArrayList<>

Comment: private void listener() {
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                for (int i = 0; i < headerArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    if (i != groupPosition) {
                        expandableListView.collapseGroup(i);
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195974/discussion-between-sandeep-kumar-and-arpi-singh).

Comment: @Piyush Thanks, it's solved. Please see updated question.

Comment: @SandeepKumar Thanks, it's solved. Please see updated question.

Comment: Great! You made as busy with code and finally issue was in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I was also working on expandable list view, fortunately i got a great example for that

Link : https://github.com/sourabhgupta811/ExpandableRecyclerView

Following is the adapter layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/head_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        tools:text="Tap to expand" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<com.example.smoothcardanimation.ExpandableLinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandableView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:expandDuration="500">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/expanded_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="This is sample text" />
</com.example.smoothcardanimation.ExpandableLinearLayout>
```

Adapter File :

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<ExpandModel> data;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private int lastExpandedCardPosition;
private int i=0;
public RecyclerViewAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.headTextView.setText("Tap to expand");
    holder.expandedTextView.setText("this is sample text");
    if(data.get(position).isExpanded()){
        holder.expandableView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.expandableView.setExpanded(true);
    }
    else{
        holder.expandableView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.expandableView.setExpanded(false);
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() 
    return data.size();
}

public void setData(List<ExpandModel> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void addItem(int i) {
    data.add(i,new ExpandModel());
    if(i<=lastExpandedCardPosition)
        lastExpandedCardPosition++;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void deleteItem(int i) {
    data.remove(i);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ExpandableLinearLayout expandableView;
    TextView headTextView;
    TextView expandedTextView;
    ExpandListener expandListener = new ExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onExpandComplete() {
            if(lastExpandedCardPosition!=getAdapterPosition() && recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(lastExpandedCardPosition)!=null){
                ((ExpandableLinearLayout)recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(lastExpandedCardPosition).itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandableView)).setExpanded(false);
                data.get(lastExpandedCardPosition).setExpanded(false);
                ((ExpandableLinearLayout)recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(lastExpandedCardPosition).itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandableView)).toggle();
            }
            else if(lastExpandedCardPosition!=getAdapterPosition() && recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(lastExpandedCardPosition)==null){
                data.get(lastExpandedCardPosition).setExpanded(false);
            }
            lastExpandedCardPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCollapseComplete() {

        }
    };
    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        headTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.head_textview);
        expandedTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expanded_textview);
        expandableView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandableView);
        expandableView.setExpandListener(expandListener);
        initializeClicks();
    }

    private void initializeClicks() {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (expandableView.isExpanded()) {
                    expandableView.setExpanded(false);
                    expandableView.toggle();
                    data.get(getAdapterPosition()).setExpanded(false);
                } else {
                    expandableView.setExpanded(true);
                    data.get(getAdapterPosition()).setExpanded(true);
                    expandableView.toggle();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Expandable View File :

```
public class ExpandableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout{
private boolean expanded;
private int duration;
private ExpandListener expandListener;

public ExpandableLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
}

public ExpandableLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(attrs);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public ExpandableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(attrs);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    TypedArray customValues = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.ExpandableLinearLayout);
    duration = customValues.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableLinearLayout_expandDuration, -1);
    customValues.recycle();
}

public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    Log.e("layout", expanded + "");
    this.expanded = expanded;
}

public void toggle() {
    if (expanded)
        expandView(this);
    else
        hideView(this);
}

private void expandView(final View view) {
    view.measure(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            , View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    final int targetHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
    // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
    view.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            view.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? targetHeight : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            view.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            expandListener.onExpandComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    if (duration == -1)
        a.setDuration((int) (targetHeight / view.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 1.5));
    else
        a.setDuration(duration);
    view.startAnimation(a);
}

private void hideView(final View view) {
    final int initialHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();

    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                view.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                view.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    if (duration == -1)
        a.setDuration((int) (initialHeight / view.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 1.5));
    else
        a.setDuration(duration);
    a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            expandListener.onCollapseComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    view.startAnimation(a);
}

public void setExpandListener(ExpandListener expandListener) {
    this.expandListener = expandListener;
}
}
```